# VS Code does not read the CSS after restart

Tags: css, django, visual-studio-code

I'm a student of programming and I just started working yesterday on VS Code. I'm trying to make a social/house rent platform by using Django/jQuery.

I made some HTML, CSS, js pages, **there is a no problem about this, everything okay and working**.. then I slept and today just turned on my pc but VS Code didn't read the CSS files (not sure about js files too) [**Update: It was reading but wasn't catch the changes**].

For example, my nav's text color is black yesterday and I changed color to white after this the page is was still black color.

I use `href="{% static 'polls/style.css'}"` method for calling static files

I tried everything but it's still wasn't reading the current files.

So i did

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
```

to (the only difference is the name of the CSS file)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
```

and renamed my **stlye**.css file to **styles**.css and bang it's **working**...

I thought it was a one time bug but it wasn't. Before 15 min ago I put my computer to sleep mode and **when I came back I solved the same problem the same way**..

Does anyone have this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: when you said "today just turned on my pc but vscode didn't read the css files" did you meant that your css is not showing on the page? because it's not vsc problem its probably from your local host or sth

Comment: actually, it was reading the current css file but wasn't catch the changes

Comment: then your problem is that your css file is being cached in the browser my friend

Comment: try shift + f5 for windows, command + shift + R for mac if it didn't help there are methods to generate unique number for each css file when it get changed like webpack for example that would help but it need more work

Comment: yes i thought something like this, because i delete my css file and page is still looking same..

Comment: check this ticket it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188544/django-css-file-cached

Comment: I put my pc to sleep mode but the error did not occur again, I will try it next time and i think it will work. Thanks a lot of..

Answer (score 1):

it is  happening to me i don't know how to fix this problem  but  what i do to make it work is:
I rename the css file to "style1.css" for example then modify here too
type="text/css" href="style1.css" it works

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

> try shift + f5 for windows, command + shift + R for mac if it didn't
> help there are methods to generate unique number for each css file
> when it get changed like webpack for example that would help but it
> need more work